# Error with some regular expressions in GAE

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I'm parsing HTML code in url var, but I have an strange problem with the following:

This line works ok `pattern = re.compile("\.html$")` but when I try this `pattern = re.compile("ps\.html$")` the function return an strange string apparalently empty. I tried the same code in pure python and works ok in both cases, but when I run it under GAE I get the problem. Could somebody try the following code? Thanks!

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Created on 24/06/2012

@author: nanchet
'''
import re
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class psLinkFinder(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "a":
            pattern = re.compile("\.html$")
            for attr in attrs:
                if attr[0] == "href" and pattern.search(attr[1]):
                    print attr[1]

url = '''
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">
 <a href="http://es.kompass.com/">
 <img class="logo"
    src="/live/images/www.kompass.com.png" alt="Kompass - Connects Business to Business" width="208" height="35" />
</a>
</div>
<div id="breadcrumb" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" itemscope="">
<a itemprop="url" href="http://es.kompass.com/live/"><span itemprop="title">Directorio de Empresas</span></a>
 >
<a itemprop="url" href=""><span itemprop="title"></span></a> &gt; </div>
<div id="main" class="cpyLst">
<div id="mainLeftColumn">
<h1 class="h1Bg">Maquinaria y equipos de España</h1>
<div class="mainBg">
<div id="box_three_companies">
<p>
    <strong>Maquinaria y bienes de equipo, consiga nuevos contactos</strong><br />
    Trabajar con empresas del sector de maquinaria y equipo es m&aacute;s f&aacute;cil si cuenta con la ayuda de un experto. Kompass le ofrece su gu&iacute;a empresarial con la que podr&aacute; encontrar clientes potenciales. &iquest;Quiere aumentar sus contactos comerciales? No lo dude, d&eacute; sus primeros pasos con Kompass.<br />
    <br />
    <strong>Dos millones de empresas ya conf&iacute;an en nosotros, aprov&eacute;chese de la visibilidad que le ofrecemos</strong><br />
    &iquest;Desea dar a conocer su actividad y sus productos o servicios en el sector de maquinaria y bienes de equipo? Kompass es el intermediario que necesita. &iexcl;Benef&iacute;ciese de nuestros soportes de comunicaci&oacute;n! Inscr&iacute;base y aumente su notoriedad y presencia.<br />
    &nbsp;</p>


        <ul class="lstTopFive">
        <li>
<strong>
<a
    href="/live/es/ES1008294/mulder-y-co--s-a.html">Mulder Y Co., S.A.</a></strong>
<address class="cpyAddress">28830 San Fernando de Henares España</address>
<p class="cpyActivity">
 MYCSA, Mulder y Co., S.A. fu&eacute; constituida en 1978 con la idea de cubrir un vac&iacute;o...</p>
<div class="cpyBtn">
<a
    title="Información detallada acerca de Mulder Y Co., S.A."
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/exit/KIM']);this.target='_blank';"
    href="http://es.kompass.com/profile_ES1008294_es/mulder-y-co.-s.a.-ps.html"><img
    alt="Información detallada acerca de Mulder Y Co., S.A." src="/live/images/pWeblink.jpg" /></a>
<a
    title="Envíenos un e-mail"
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/exit/KIM']);this.target='_blank';"
    href="http://es.kompass.com/contact_ES1008294_es/mulder-y-co.-s.a..html"><img
    alt="Envíenos un e-mail"
    src="/live/images/pContact.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
</li><li>
<strong>
<a
    href="/live/es/ES0015070/comspain-xxi-s-a.html">Comspain XXI, S.A.</a></strong>
<address class="cpyAddress">28015 Madrid España</address>
<p class="cpyActivity">
FABRICACION NACIONAL: MANUTENCI&Oacute;N-MATERIAL VIBRANTE: Extractores - Precribadores -...</p>
<div class="cpyBtn">
<a
    title="Información detallada acerca de Comspain XXI, S.A."
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/exit/KIM']);this.target='_blank';"
    href="http://es.kompass.com/profile_ES0015070_es/comspain-xxi-s.a.-ps.html"><img
    alt="Información detallada acerca de Comspain XXI, S.A." src="/live/images/pWeblink.jpg" /></a>
<a
    title="Envíenos un e-mail"
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/exit/KIM']);this.target='_blank';"
    href="http://es.kompass.com/contact_ES0015070_es/comspain-xxi-s.a..html"><img
    alt="Envíenos un e-mail"
    src="/live/images/pContact.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
</li>
    <li>
<strong>
<a
    href="/live/es/ES1041656/montajes-industriales-eos-s-a.html">Montajes Industriales Eos, S.A.</a></strong>
<address class="cpyAddress">28850 Torrejón de Ardoz España</address>
<p class="cpyActivity">
 MONTAJES INDUSTRIALES EOS  es una empresa fundada en el a&ntilde;o 1989. Su actividad principal...</p>
<div class="cpyBtn">
<a
    title="Información detallada acerca de Montajes Industriales Eos, S.A."
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/exit/KIM']);this.target='_blank';"
    href="http://es.kompass.com/profile_ES1041656_es/montajes-industriales-eos-s.a.-ps.html"><img
    alt="Información detallada acerca de Montajes Industriales Eos, S.A." src="/live/images/pWeblink.jpg" /></a>
<a
    title="Envíenos un e-mail"
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/exit/KIM']);this.target='_blank';"
    href="http://es.kompass.com/contact_ES1041656_es/montajes-industriales-eos-s.a..html"><img
    alt="Envíenos un e-mail"
    src="/live/images/pContact.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
</li>
<li>
<strong>
<a
    href="/live/es/ES1036232/construcciones-metalicas-albero-s-l.html">Construcciones Met&aacute;licas Albero, S.L.</a></strong>
<address class="cpyAddress">28500 Arganda del Rey España</address>
<p class="cpyActivity">
ESTA EMPRESA CUENTA CON EL PATROCINIO DE LA C&Aacute;MARA DE COMERCIO DE MADRID CONSTRUCCIONES...</p>
<div class="cpyBtn">
<a
    title="Información detallada acerca de Construcciones Metálicas Albero, S.L."
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/exit/KIM']);this.target='_blank';"
    href="http://es.kompass.com/profile_ES1036232_es/construcciones-metálicas-albero-s.l.-ps.html"><img
    alt="Información detallada acerca de Construcciones Metálicas Albero, S.L." src="/live/images/pWeblink.jpg" /></a>
<a
    title="Envíenos un e-mail"
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/exit/KIM']);this.target='_blank';"
    href="http://es.kompass.com/contact_ES1036232_es/construcciones-metálicas-albero-s.l..html"><img
    alt="Envíenos un e-mail"
    src="/live/images/pContact.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
</li>    <script type="text/javascript">
    setNedStatResultList('ES1036232', 'paid','country.ESP','Construcciones Metálicas Albero, S.L.', '3','http://fr.sitestat.com/kompass/kompass-es/s?esp.es.lc.gs.cat.subcat.GSesESP5301.company_list.result.1&amp;user_country=ESP', 'ESP');
    </script>
    <li>
<strong>
<a
    href="/live/es/ES0016818/electricfor-s-a.html">Electricfor, S.A.</a></strong>
<address class="cpyAddress">08191 Rubí España</address>
<p class="cpyActivity">
 Resistencias Resistencias el&eacute;ctricas calefactoras. Resistencias para l&iacute;quidos,...</p>
<div class="cpyBtn">
<a
    title="Información detallada acerca de Electricfor, S.A."
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/exit/KIM']);this.target='_blank';"
    href="http://es.kompass.com/profile_ES0016818_es/electricfor-s.a.-ps.html"><img
    alt="Información detallada acerca de Electricfor, S.A." src="/live/images/pWeblink.jpg" /></a>
<a
    title="Envíenos un e-mail"
    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/exit/KIM']);this.target='_blank';"
    href="http://es.kompass.com/contact_ES0016818_es/electricfor-s.a..html"><img
    alt="Envíenos un e-mail"
    src="/live/images/pContact.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
</li>
    </ul>        
<br/><div class="paginationControl"><span class="active">1</span><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-2.html">2</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-3.html">3</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-4.html">4</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-5.html">5</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-6.html">6</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-7.html">7</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-8.html">8</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-9.html">9</a><br/><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-10.html">10</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-20.html">20</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-30.html">30</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-40.html">40</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-50.html">50</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-60.html">60</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-70.html">70</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-80.html">80</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-90.html">90</a><br/><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-100.html">100</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-200.html">200</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-300.html">300</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-400.html">400</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-500.html">500</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-600.html">600</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-700.html">700</a><a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-757.html">757</a></div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<div style="margin:15px 0"><p>
    Con nuestra gu&iacute;a Kompass, podr&aacute; consultar listados de empresas especializadas en maquinaria y bienes de equipo.&nbsp;Podr&aacute; encontrar&nbsp;resultados precisos en la actividad que necesite.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>

<div id="mainRightColumn">

<div style="text-align:center">
<a class="no_border" href="http://webdemo.kompass.fr/WebDemo_en.html">
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="sideBox greyBg">
<div class="title">Búsqueda</div>
<div class="margin10">
<ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li><span class='filtreName'>Sectores : </span> <a href="/live/es/g53/fabricacion-industria-1.html">Fabricaci&oacute;n e Industria</a></li><li> <a href="/live/es/g5301/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-1.html"><img src="/live/img/commun/puce_tree.png" alt="*"/>Maquinaria y equipos</a></li></ul>
</div>
</div><div class="sideBox greenBg">
<div class="title">Restringir la búsqueda</div>
<div class="margin10 refineSection">
<strong>Comunidad Autónoma</strong>
<ul>
<li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp01/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,andalucia-1.html'>Andaluc&iacute;a</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp02/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,aragon-1.html'>Arag&oacute;n</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp03/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,asturias-1.html'>Asturias</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp04/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,baleares-1.html'>Baleares</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp05/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,canarias-1.html'>Canarias</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp08/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,cantabria-1.html'>Cantabria</a></li></ul>
<ul id="regionlist">
<li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp09/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,castilla-y-leon-1.html'>Castilla y Le&oacute;n</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp07/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,castilla-la-mancha-1.html'>Castilla-La Mancha</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp06/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,cataluna-1.html'>Catalu&ntilde;a</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp10/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,ceuta-y-melilla-1.html'>Ceuta y Melilla</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp17/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,comunidad-valenciana-1.html'>Comunidad Valenciana</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp11/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,extremadura-1.html'>Extremadura</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp12/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,galicia-1.html'>Galicia</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp16/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,la-rioja-1.html'>La Rioja</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp13/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,madrid-1.html'>Madrid</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp14/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,murcia-1.html'>Murcia</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp15/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,navarra-1.html'>Navarra</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5301resp18/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos,pais-vasco-1.html'>Pa&iacute;s Vasco</a></li></ul>
 <a id="btnregionlist" class="toogleLink">Mostrar todas las regiones</a>
<strong>Sectores</strong>
<ul>
<li><a href='/live/es/g530101/fabricacion-industria/turbinas-motores-maquinas-vapor-1.html'>Turbinas, motores, m&aacute;quinas de vapor</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530102/fabricacion-industria/bombas-compresores-equipos-neumaticos-hidraulicos-1.html'>Bombas, compresores, equipos neum&aacute;ticos e hidr&aacute;ulicos </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530103/fabricacion-industria/calderas-hornos-quemadores-1.html'>Calderas, hornos y quemadores</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530104w40440/fabricacion-industria/intercambiadores-torres-enfriamiento-condensadores-radiadores-1.html'>Intercambiadores, torres de enfriamiento, condensadores y radiadores</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530105/fabricacion-industria/fabricas-equipos-ventilacion-calefaccion-aire-acondicionado-1.html'>F&aacute;bricas y equipos de ventilaci&oacute;n, calefacci&oacute;n, aire acondicionado</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530106/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-agricultura-silvicultura-acuicultura-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para la agricultura, silvicultura y acuicultura</a></li></ul>
<ul id="sectorlist">
<li><a href='/live/es/g530107/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-las-industrias-agroalimentaria-bebidas-tabaco-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para las industrias agroalimentaria, bebidas y tabaco</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530108/fabricacion-industria/equipos-industria-quimica-farmaceutica-1.html'>Equipos para la industria qu&iacute;mica y farmace&uacute;tica</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530109/fabricacion-industria/equipos-proceso-plastico-caucho-1.html'>Equipos para el proceso de pl&aacute;stico y caucho</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530110/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-envasado-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para el envasado</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530111/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-textiles-confeccion-cuero-zapateria-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para textiles, confecci&oacute;n, cuero y zapater&iacute;a</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530112/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-fabricar-pasta-papel-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para fabricar pasta y papel</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530113/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-impresion-encuadernacion-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para impresi&oacute;n y encuadernaci&oacute;n</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530115/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-minas-canteras-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para minas y canteras </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530116/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-exploracion-extraccion-aceite-gas-agua-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para la exploraci&oacute;n y extracci&oacute;n de aceite, gas y agua</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530117/fabricacion-industria/fabricas-equipos-productos-minerales-metalicos-1.html'>F&aacute;bricas y equipos para productos minerales no met&aacute;licos</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530118/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-construccion-ingenieria-obras-publicas-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para la construcci&oacute;n e ingenier&iacute;a de obras p&uacute;blicas</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530119/fabricacion-industria/equipamiento-ascensores-elevadores-transporte-industrial-1.html'>Equipamiento para ascensores, elevadores y transporte industrial</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530120/fabricacion-industria/fabricas-maquinaria-equipos-metalurgia-metalisteria-1.html'>F&aacute;bricas, maquinaria y equipos para metalurgia y metalister&iacute;a</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530121/fabricacion-industria/fabricas-maquinaria-equipos-trabajar-madera-corcho-1.html'>F&aacute;bricas, maquinaria y equipos para trabajar la madera y el corcho</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530122/fabricacion-industria/herramientas-trabajar-metal-1.html'>Herramientas para trabajar el metal</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530123w47900/fabricacion-industria/instalaciones-maquinaria-equipos-montaje-1.html'>Instalaciones, maquinaria y equipos de montaje</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530124w37500/fabricacion-industria/sistemas-automatizacion-servomecanismos-1.html'>Sistemas de automatizaci&oacute;n y servomecanismos</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530125/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-precision-las-industrias-piedras-preciosas-relojes-joyeria-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos de precisi&oacute;n para las industrias de piedras preciosas, relojes y joyer&iacute;a</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530126/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-las-industrias-electrica-electronica-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para las industrias el&eacute;ctrica y electr&oacute;nica</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530127/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-tratamiento-agua-vertidos-aguas-residuales-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para el tratamiento del agua, vertidos y aguas residuales</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530128/fabricacion-industria/instalaciones-contra-incendio-sistemas-seguridad-1.html'>Instalaciones contra incendio, sistemas de seguridad </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530129w40700/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-cocinas-hosteleria-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos para cocinas de hosteler&iacute;a</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g530130/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-especializada-usos-industriales-diversos-equipos-pago-previo-tragaperras-maquinas-expendedoras-1.html'>Otras m&aacute;quinas y equipos</a></li></ul>
 <a id="btnsectorlist" class="toogleLink">Mostrar todos los sectores de actividad</a>
<strong>Categorías relacionadas</strong>
<ul>
<li><a href='/live/es/g53019901w84400/fabricacion-industria/proyectos-industriales-llave-mano-1.html'>Proyectos industriales llave en mano</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g53019902w85720/fabricacion-industria/servicios-ensayo-maquinaria-equipos-1.html'>Servicios de ensayo de maquinaria y equipos</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g53019903w83200/fabricacion-industria/alquiler-maquinaria-herramientas-equipos-industriales-1.html'>Alquiler de maquinaria, herramientas y equipos industriales</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g53019904/fabricacion-industria/maquinaria-equipos-comercio-1.html'>Maquinaria y equipos (comercio)</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g53019905w84800/fabricacion-industria/consultores-ingenieria-mecanica-1.html'>Consultores en ingenier&iacute;a mec&aacute;nica</a></li></ul>
<strong>Otros sectores</strong>
<ul>
<li><a href='/live/es/g5302/fabricacion-industria/metalurgia-metalisteria-productos-metalicos-1.html'>Metalurgia, metalister&iacute;a y productos met&aacute;licos</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5303/fabricacion-industria/material-electrico-electronico-1.html'>Material el&eacute;ctrico y electr&oacute;nico </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5304/fabricacion-industria/equipos-instrumentos-test-medicion-opticos-precision-1.html'>Equipos e instrumentos para test y medici&oacute;n.

Equipos &oacute;pticos y de precisi&oacute;n.</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5305/fabricacion-industria/medios-transporte-1.html'>Medios de transporte </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5306/fabricacion-industria/instalaciones-contra-incendio-sistemas-seguridad-1.html'>Instalaciones contra incendio y sistemas de seguridad </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5307/fabricacion-industria/equipos-suministros-hospitales-centros-medicos-dentistas-veterinarios-1.html'>Equipos y suministros para hospitales, centros m&eacute;dicos, dentistas y veterinarios </a></li></ul>
<ul id="sectorBrotherlist">
<li><a href='/live/es/g5308/fabricacion-industria/productos-caucho-plasticos-1.html'>Productos de caucho y pl&aacute;sticos </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5309/fabricacion-industria/productos-quimicos-farmaceuticos-1.html'>Productos qu&iacute;micos y farmac&eacute;uticos </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5310/fabricacion-industria/madera-mobliario-productos-1.html'>Madera, mobliario y productos de madera</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5311/fabricacion-industria/productos-minerales-vidrio-ceramicas-1.html'>Productos minerales, vidrio y cer&aacute;micas</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5312/fabricacion-industria/alimentos-preparados-bebidas-1.html'>Alimentos preparados y bebidas</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5313/fabricacion-industria/productos-tabaco-articulos-fumadores-1.html'>Productos de tabaco y articulos para fumadores </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5315/fabricacion-industria/tejidos-ropa-cuero-calzado-1.html'>Tejidos, ropa, cuero, calzado.</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5316/fabricacion-industria/papel-productos-1.html'>Papel y productos de papel </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5317/fabricacion-industria/servicios-editoriales-1.html'>Servicios editoriales</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5318/fabricacion-industria/material-oficina-ordenadores-perifericos-1.html'>Material de oficina. Ordenadores y perif&eacute;ricos. </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5319/fabricacion-industria/calefaccion-ventilacion-aire-acondicionado-refrigeracion-1.html'>Calefacci&oacute;n, ventilaci&oacute;n y aire acondicionado, refrigeraci&oacute;n</a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5320/fabricacion-industria/ingenieria-nuclear-1.html'>Ingenier&iacute;a nuclear </a></li><li><a href='/live/es/g5321/fabricacion-industria/bolsas-sacos-materiales-envasado-equipos-energia-alternativa-1.html'>Otras industrias</a></li></ul>
 <a id="btnsectorBrotherlist" class="toogleLink">Mostrar todos los sectores de actividad</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sideBox greyBg">
<div class="title">Buscar por marcas comerciales</div>
<div class="margin10"><ul>
<li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-bomag-1.html'>BOMAG</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-maquinaria-vinas-1.html'>MAQUINARIA VI&Ntilde;AS</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-jevsa-1.html'>JEVSA</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-bison-1.html'>BISON</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-abus-1.html'>ABUS</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-cat-1.html'>CAT</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-3m-1.html'>3M</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-barbothan-1.html'>BARBOTHAN</a></li></ul>
<ul id="tmlist">
<li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-aap-1.html'>AAP</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-burckhardt-compression-1.html'>BURCKHARDT COMPRESSION</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-branson-1.html'>BRANSON</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-elan-1.html'>ELAN</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-tane-1.html'>TAN&Eacute;</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-comspain-1.html'>COMSPAIN</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-ifema-feria-de-madrid-1.html'>IFEMA, FERIA DE MADRID</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-alutop-1.html'>ALUTOP</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-sick-1.html'>SICK</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-cableeater-1.html'>CABLEEATER</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-arvipo-1.html'>ARVIPO</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-tv-95-premier-1.html'>TV 95 PREMIER</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-bacti-sopor-1.html'>BACTI-SOPOR</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-alkitorc-1.html'>ALKITORC</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-cfor-1.html'>CFOR</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-h-s-1.html'>H&amp;S</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-cartepillar-1.html'>CARTEPILLAR</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-mapres-1.html'>MAPRES</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-epsilon-1.html'>EPSILON</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-79-vacio-1.html'>79 VACIO</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-biogon-1.html'>BIOGON</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-bolondi-1.html'>BOLONDI</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-greenfield-1.html'>GREENFIELD</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-hisselektronik-1.html'>HISSELEKTRONIK</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-tane-hermetic-1.html'>TAN&Eacute; HERM&Eacute;TIC</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-aquapanel-1.html'>AQUAPANEL</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-sick-ivp-1.html'>SICK IVP</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-hook-loop-1.html'>HOOK &amp; LOOP</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-conduc-bat-1.html'>CONDUC-BAT</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-mirage-1.html'>MIRAGE</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-case-1.html'>CASE</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-mezclamed-1.html'>MEZCLAMED</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-indexator-1.html'>INDEXATOR</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-aapel-1.html'>AAPEL</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-carbocat-1.html'>CARBOCAT</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-uraca-1.html'>URACA</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-haug-1.html'>HAUG</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-rst-1.html'>RST</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-danogips-1.html'>DANOGIPS</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-sick-maihak-1.html'>SICK MAIHAK</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-wrap-it-ties-1.html'>WRAP-IT-TIES</a></li><li>&raquo; <a class='avec_fleche_noire' href='/live/es/t-peinemann-1.html'>PEINEMANN</a></li></ul>
 <a id="btntmlist" class="toogleLink">Mostrar todas las marcas comerciales</a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="footer">
<ul>
<li><a class="color_bleu" onclick="this.target='_blank'" href="http://empresas.kompass.com/">Directorio de empresas españolas</a></li>
</ul><div id="address_footer">
<address><strong>Kompass Spain (Central)</strong><br />C/ Explanada, 8. 1º B. 28040. Madrid <br/>

Tel&eacute;fono : 917 697 165&nbsp;Fax : 917 697 165</address>
</div>
<div id="copyright">Copyright KOMPASS &copy; 2012</div>
</div>

<div id="contactPlusCard">
<span class="cpCorner es"></span>
<div>
<p class="txt"><strong style="color: red;">¿Busca un producto o servicio específico?</strong><br/><br/><strong>Contact + </strong> selecciona en su base de datos mundial las empresas que se ajustan más a su solicitud.</p>
<p class="btn"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.kompass-int.com/contact_plus/intl/index_form.php?lang=es&pays_franchise=ES">Ir!</a><a style="margin-left:20px" target="_blank" href="http://webdemo.kompass.fr/suppliers-contactPlus/es">Ver la demo</a></p>
</div>
<a class="button close"></a>
<a class="cross close"></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
'''
parser = psLinkFinder()
parser.feed(url)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you double the backslash in that string? Or use an `r` prefix like `r"ps\.html"`? Otherwise you're relying on the unknown escape sequence `\.` being passed through.

Comment: How are you running this under app engine?

Comment: @AlanCurry thanks but I already test that and it does the same :(

Comment: @GuidovanRossum Im running this with dev_appserver.py and then from the browser

Comment: If you treat the result as an array and make a "for" to print that, you'll see that the result is correct but is deformed or something (sorry for my english level...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
re.compile(r'ps\.html$')
```